# FTP through a NAT with ftp.exe fails with "Unable to build data connection: Connection refused"

Tags: windows, ftp

How to FTP through a NAT with ftp.exe?

```
ftp my.ftp.it
Connesso a my.ftp.it
220 FTP Server ready.
500 OPTS UTF8 not understood
Utente (my.ftp.it:(none)): user
331 Password required for user
Password:
230 User abox logged in.
ftp> dir
500 Illegal PORT command
425 Unable to build data connection: Connection refused
```

**425 Unable to build data connection: Connection refused**

- Connection with windows Explorer work
- Connection with FILEZILLA (active mode) and ip advanced mode work

where is the configuration for ftp.exe?